# Should I use “when” or “where” in this riddle?

Tags: word-choice

Here is the riddle:

> When does Christmas come before Thanksgiving?
>   The answer is: "in the dictionary".

When I told that riddle, a coworker said it should be "where" instead
of "when".  Is “when” incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

You can make the joke with either word.

With "Where" the meaning could initially be understood as "Where in the world ..." (This meaning is then unexpectedly changed by the answer)

With "When" the meaning could be understood as "In which situations ..." The answer would fit with this meaning, but the situation is unexpected. The joke, in either case, is the unexpected answer.